Resolve Generic of Generic
I'm trying to create a reusable utility type in TypeScript that works with any map type conforming to a generic structure. Here's my basic setup:
type SomeMap<T> = {
  [key: string]: T;
};

I need to define a Resolve type that can dynamically work with any map type extending SomeMap. Here's my attempt that results in errors:
type Resolve<T, K extends keyof Map, Map extends SomeMap<T>> = {
  result: Map<T>[K]; // Syntax error: can only be: Map[K]
};

This fails because TypeScript doesn't support this form of generics nesting or constraint directly. I'm looking for a way to make Resolve work with any type that matches SomeMap without hardcoding the map type into the Resolve definition.
Clearly, it's possible to hardcode the map in the following way:
type ResolveWorks<T, K extends keyof SomeMap<T>> = {
  result: SomeMap<T>[K];
};

However, this approach does not meet my requirements because it lacks reusability—I need a solution that is adaptable to different map structures without specifying SomeMap directly.

I think this is where the infer keyword and conditional types come in handy. You could do something like: type Resolve<T> = T extends SomeMap<infer R> ? { result: R } : never.

c.f.: K extends keyof Map, Map extends SomeMap<T> <-- Might it be because Map<> is already its own type? What if you use a name like M instead?

What does it mean for something to "extend SomeMap"? I think you'll run into the fundamental lack of TS's representation of "higher kinded types" as requested in ms/TS#1213, but maybe you have something a little more specific in mind that is possible? Anyway, please [edit] to give examples of what your "extensions" of SomeMap might like.

@jcalz Yes that would be the answer that true HKT are not possible.
Thanks for all the answers.

Workaround:
type IsString<T> = T extends string ? true : false;

type IsNumber<T> = T extends number ? true : false;

type Resolve<T, HS, HN> = IsString<T> extends true
  ? HS
  : IsNumber<T> extends true
  ? HN
  : never;

type HandleString<T> = {
  type: 'string';
  v: T;
};

type HandleNumber<T> = {
  type: 'number';
  v: T;
};

type Result<T> = Resolve<string, HandleString<T>, HandleNumber<T>>;


